# Problems with express

Tags: node.js, express

is there a reason why when ran, this isn't running? Why wouldn't the code be touching this?

```
app.get('/client.html', function (req, res) {
  console.log('he');
  res.redirect('../Documents/Code/public/grumpy.html');
});
```

update from comments:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
module.exports = app;
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/practiceCode/client.html');
   //res.redirect('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/Code/public/grumpy.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  io.sockets.emit('broadcast');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('hekki');
  res.redirect('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/Code/public/grumpy.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: what error did you get ? can you post the complete error logs here..

Comment: I don't get errors, "he" doesn't print

Comment: I think youre doing it wrong.. this is the proper way of using app.get..for example:  
```app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})``` it means when you access the root of your app(/) it will print a message

Comment: i could be using it wrong, but i did that and still it doesnt print "he"

Comment: hm, can you paste here the detailed source code ?

Answer (score 0):

From your code

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/practiceCode/client.html');
   //res.redirect('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/Code/public/grumpy.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  io.sockets.emit('broadcast');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('hekki');
  res.redirect('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/Code/public/grumpy.html');
});
```

If Node hits on first route handler when path is '/' it will not come to the second one. 
And I suggest you to set a static folder and put those html files in there and send those file on client request. code is below.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

'public' is the folder in your server. then specify the path to the html file from this public folder.
hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: how do you define path? like var path='C:/Users/O77616/Documents/Code/public/grumpy.html'

Comment: @juniperWhite I am very sorry about incompleteness. path is a dependency. import it as `var path = require('path');`